# Unable to move files completely to S3 bucket using AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get past a road block situation related to S3.

Background: From my mobile app users can pick upto 10 images and post it to server. This is received and moved to concerned folders in AWS instance - Let's call it instance "A" for the purpose of our discussion.  As and when the file is moved to instance "A" we are calling "moveFileToS3" . The code looks something like this.

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
                    {
                            $file_info = $file['name'];
                            $extension = pathinfo($file['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                            $destination_file_name = $imagesMoved . '-'. $sku . '.'. $extension;
                            $file_path = $images_directory . $destination_file_name;

                            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file_path))
                            {
                                    $imagesMoved++;
                                   //Move the file to S3
                                    moveFileToS3($destination_file_name, $images_directory, $parent_folder . '/' . $images_folder . '/');

                            }

                            if (intval($imagesMoved) == intval($totalFileCount))
                            {
                                    $image_moved = true;
                                    //Begin to update the DB
                            }
                    }
```

When this call (moveFileToS3) is NOT made.. all the files selected by the user make it to instance "A".

But when this call(moveFileToS3) is made... not all the files selected by the user make it to instance "A" and only a few files from instance "A" get moved to S3 location. Neither set of instructions after $image_moved = true get executed.

Any assistance to get past this situation would be very much appreciated. I have attached the file that has the method "moveFileToS3" for your quick reference.

```
<?php
require  '../api/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Common\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

function moveFileToS3($fileName, $fileLocation, $targetLocation)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $region  = 'xxxxx';
    $version = 'xxxxx';
    $bucket = 'xx-xxxxxx-xxxxx';
    $endpoint = 'xxxxxxxx.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com';
    $key = 'xxxxxx';
    $secret = 'xxxxxxxxx';

    $fileFullPathLocal = $fileLocation.$fileName;

    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => $version,
        'region'  => $region,
        'debug'   => true,
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => $key,
            'secret' => $secret,
        ]
    ]);

    // Prepare the upload parameters.
    $uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3, $fileFullPathLocal, [
        'bucket' => $bucket,
        'key'    => $targetLocation.$fileName
    ]);

    // Perform the upload.
    try
    {
        $responseLogFile = fopen("../log/S3UploadLog_".date("Y-m-d").".log", "a+");
        fwrite($responseLogFile, '['.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").']: Upload Started : '.$fileName. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL);
        fclose($responseLogFile);

        $result = $uploader->upload();

        $responseLogFile = fopen("../log/S3UploadLog_".date("Y-m-d").".log", "a+");
        fwrite($responseLogFile, '['.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").']: Upload Finished : '.$fileName. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL);
//             fwrite($responseLogFile, '['.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").']: Upload Result : '.$result. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL);
        fwrite($responseLogFile, '['.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").']: Object Url : '.$result['ObjectURL']. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL);
        fclose($responseLogFile);

//             echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}" . PHP_EOL;
        unlink($fileFullPathLocal);


    }
    catch (MultipartUploadException $e)
    {
        $responseLogFile = fopen("../log/S3UploadLog_".date("Y-m-d").".log", "a+");
        fwrite($responseLogFile, '['.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").']: Upload Failed : '.$fileName. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL);
        fclose($responseLogFile);

        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to issue when you move file from your local dev sever to a bucket.. But when moved to AWS environment.. works without any issues